# How to draw selection / bounding box / rectangle on google map using google.maps.Rectangle object and check if markers fall within it

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How do I draw a google.maps.Rectangle on a google map while holding the shift key and then once its drawn do something with its boundaries (like return all markers that fall within it)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I had the need to draw a simple rectangle on a google map and return an array of markers that fall within the rectangle. Surprisingly I couldn't find a simple example of this on the web. So I am posting this to help others with the same issue.

If you can see any glaring issues, please let me know although it seems to work for my needs at the moment.

The code assumes you have jQuery and have already stored your google map object in a variable called themap.

```
var shiftdown = false;
var gribBoundingBox = null;
var boxcomplete = false;
var original_click_pos = null;

$(window).keydown(function (evt) {
    if (evt.which === 16) { // shift
        shiftdown = true;
    }
}).keyup(function (evt) {
    if (evt.which === 16) { // shift
        shiftdown = false;
    }
});

function cleargribBoundingBox(){
    if(gribBoundingBox !== null){
        gribBoundingBox.setMap(null); // remove the rectangle
    }
    boxcomplete = false;
original_click_pos = null;
}
google.maps.event.addListener(themap, 'mousedown', function (e) {
    if (shiftdown) {
        themap.setOptions({
            draggable: false
        });
        cleargribBoundingBox();
  original_click_pos = e.latLng;
        gribBoundingBox = new google.maps.Rectangle({
            map: themap,
            bounds: new google.maps.LatLngBounds(original_click_pos,original_click_pos),
            fillOpacity: 0.15,
            strokeWeight: 0.9,
            clickable: false
        });
    }
});
google.maps.event.addListener(themap, 'mousemove', function (e) {
    if(gribBoundingBox !== null){
        if(!boxcomplete){
            //moving mouse accross map, box is in process of being drawn
            //lets update its bounds
    var newbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(original_click_pos,original_click_pos);
            newbounds.extend(e.latLng);
            gribBoundingBox.setBounds(newbounds);
        } else{
            //moving mouse accross map, box is present
        }
    } else {
        //moving mouse over map, no bounding box present
        //either no bounding box has been made yet or we are not holding shift and we are just dragging the map around
    }
});
google.maps.event.addListener(themap, 'mouseup', function (e) {
    if(gribBoundingBox !== null){ //we just completed a box
    if(!boxcomplete){ //we just completed a box
              boxcomplete = true;
              themap.setOptions({
                    draggable: true
              });
              //check if markers are in the box
              /*var boundsSelectionArea = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                    gribBoundingBox.getBounds().getSouthWest(),
                    gribBoundingBox.getBounds().getNorthEast()
              );*/
    }
}
});
```

[https://jsfiddle.net/x1xpmhvk/](https://jsfiddle.net/x1xpmhvk/9/)

Comment: Should I vote it up for you?

Comment: Only if it works for you and is helpful

Comment: Please comment or upvote.

Comment: @Rel, This does not work for me. This only creates a dot over the map wherever I click. I am not able to draw a rectangle. Can you check and update.

Comment: I searched for this question before and remember the example worked. But now it stopped working already.